# Qt based GUI creation for scripts

Tags: qt, user-interface, gtk

Is there any qt based application similar to gtk server?

I need a gui for a bash script. I found gtk-server is very suitable for my needs. However, (mostly because of personal reasons) I prefer Qt over gtk.

Is there any Qt based solution for enabling quick access to GUIs from scripting languages?

Answer (score 1):

PyQt and PyGTK bindings for python can help you